# Circular Reference with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code for mongoose schemas

```
var EstacionSchema = new Schema({
    nombre          : {type : String, required: true, unique: true}
  , zona            : {type : String, required: true}
  , rutas           : [Ruta]
})

mongoose.model('Estacion', EstacionSchema)

var RutaSchema = new Schema({
    nombre          : {type : String, required: true, unique: true, uppercase: true}
  , estaciones      : [Estacion]
})

mongoose.model('Ruta', RutaSchema)
```

however when i try it it shows

```
ReferenceError: Ruta is not defined
```

I am not sure how to handle either this circular schema when declaring models in mongoose or how to handle Many to Many relations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off you are referencing variables that don't exist. You'd reference it via `RutaSchema` or `mongoose.model('Ruta');`.

I'd try

```
var EstacionSchema = new Schema({
    nombre          : {type : String, required: true, unique: true}
  , zona            : {type : String, required: true}
})

mongoose.model('Estacion', EstacionSchema)

var RutaSchema = new Schema({
    nombre          : {type : String, required: true, unique: true, uppercase: true}
  , estaciones      : [EstacionSchema]  // or mongoose.Model('Estacion');
})

// Add reference to ruta
EstacionSchema.add({rutas: [RutaSchema]});
mongoose.model('Ruta', RutaSchema)
```